# Support for package "com.ibm.misc" and its classes

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I wanted to decode a Base64 string in my XPage for which I was using `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` class. But according to Java [developer should not write programs that call 'sun' packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html). I was searching for an alternative when I stumbled on `com.ibm.misc.BASE64Decoder`. It worked for me with same results as `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`. So I would like to know if it is okay for developers to use this package and its classes? Or is it to be avoided like 'sun' package?

Also I know that I can use [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) for Base64 but I would like to minimize my dependency on external JARs.

Comment: what's wrong with [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter#parseBase64Binary`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: @mre: I really wasn't aware that such class existed in Java. Thanks! So I guess for encoding I would be using `printBase64Binary`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `com.ibm.misc.BASE64Decoder` you'll have exactly the same problem as with `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`: it's an internal class which only exists in a specific JVM implementation, in this case IBM's JVM.

Note that there is no `com.ibm.misc.BASE64Decoder` in Oracle's JVM, so if you use this class, your program is not going to work on Oracle's JVM; it will fail with a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

You could use the method that mre refers to in his comment, which is in the class `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` - part of the JAXB API, which is part of the standard Java API (since Java SE 6).

Comment: This is true, but he's working with IBM's XPages server.  Nothing he does there is likely to ever run on anything other than the IBM JVM.